# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error, but clearing the cache doesn't solve it

Tags: linux, networking, dns

I have a Debian Stretch system. Since I tried to configure one old network printer it happens that loading the web page in any browser ends with error `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`. I tried clearing the DNS cache, adding DNS servers `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` to NetworkManager or /etc/resolv.conf, restarting the router, NetworkingManager, pc,... If it helps, then it's only for a while. Actually it switches between "working fine for two minutes" and "not working for 5 minutes" over and over again. Pages like google / search work fine. 
If I do `host <url that cannot be loaded>`, I get the correct IP address.

This system is a dual boot with Windows. On Windows it works better, although I have to clear dns cache from time to time as well.

Thx

Comment: What do you get from `host -t A <domain>` and `host -t AAAA <domain>`?

Comment: @grawity `<domain> has address <ip addr>` from `A` type and `has no AAAA record` from `AAAA` type, which is what I get on a different working computer on the different network as well.